# Ocultar URL en barra de direcciones del navegador

Tags: javascript, c#, html, bootstrap, asp

Tengo una aplicacion en aspx y utilizo el navbar de bootstrap para armar el menu de navegación, mi pregunta es de que manera puedo ocultar la url en el navegador de modo que cada vez que cambie de pagina no me aparezca la ruta, yo el menu lo armo dinamicamente desde la BD, el codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="<%=dsMenuPadres.Tables["MenuPadres"].Rows[i]["PATH"].ToString() %>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  id="<%=dsMenuPadres.Tables["MenuPadres"].Rows[i]["NOMBRE"].ToString() %>" >
        <%= dsMenuPadres.Tables["MenuPadres"].Rows[i]["NOMBRE"].ToString() %> <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <% if (objControllerSeg.GetMenuHijos(dsMenuPadres.Tables["MenuPadres"].Rows[i]["ID_MODULO"].ToString(), int.Parse(Session["idRol"].ToString())))
       {
          dsMenuHijos = objControllerSeg.DsReturn;
          if (dsMenuHijos.Tables["MenuHijos"].Rows.Count > 0) 
          { 
           %>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <%
                for (int j = 0; j < dsMenuHijos.Tables["MenuHijos"].Rows.Count; j++)
                {                                         
                 %>                     
                     <li><a   href="<%=dominio+dsMenuHijos.Tables["MenuHijos"].Rows[j]["PATH"].ToString() %>" id="<%=dsMenuHijos.Tables["MenuHijos"].Rows[j]["ID_MODULO"].ToString() %>"><%= dsMenuHijos.Tables["MenuHijos"].Rows[j]["NOMBRE"].ToString() %></a></li>
             <% }%>
           </ul>
        <% } %>                                       

    <%}%>
</li>
```

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es que la dirección no aparezca en la barra de direcciones?¿O simplemente que no cambie al navegar de una página a otra?

Comment: Lo que quiero es que no cambie la dirección al navegar de una pagina a otra.

Answer (score 2):

Esto que planteas no se puede conseguir, cuando defines un link al presionarlo el browser navegara al mismo y lo mostrara en la barra de direcciones, esto no puede evitarlo.

Ahora bien si creas una aplicacion que utilice `<frameset>` esto evita que la url cambia cuando navegas de una pagina a otra, pero no es para nada recomendado si estas aplicando bootstrap, por lo tanto esta descartado.

Otra tecnica aplicar algun framework del lado del cliente, como ser `Angular` al crear un desarrollo [SPA (Simple Page Application)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) este tipo de estructura permite navegar entre las diferentes view sin mostrar la url real del template que cargan ya que en realidad lo hacen visualizando dentro de un `ng-view`

[Single Page Apps with AngularJS Routing and Templating](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating)